# Simulating resonant LLC converter issues

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, h-bridge, resonant-converter

I'm trying to learn how this topology works to learn about high-power converter design.

I have been following this application note from Infineon, and have been able to reproduce the numbers and methodology given to get to their design: [PDF for infineon app note AN 2012-09](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Application_Note_Resonant+LLC+Converter+Operation+and+Design_Infineon.pdf?fileId=db3a30433a047ba0013a4a60e3be64a1)

My issue comes from trying to simulate the given circuit. No matter the topology, if it's half-bridge or full-bridge for the switches, or full-wave or full-bridge for the rectification, I can't seem to get the proper output.

I believe that it's because of the secondary for the transformer, but I'm not exactly sure why, as I believe that I have the correct value for the secondary inductance.

You can see the spice model in the image below:

[image: circuit simulation]

Comment: And the proper output would be what? What is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simulating an LLC converter is not overly complicated but it's true that you need the right components values for starting. Why don't you try the free ready-made LLC [template](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) that you can download from my [webpage](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Spice.htm)? The circuit is shown below and works on the free demo version of SIMPLIS:

[image]

It operates open-loop and uses perfect switches with non-linearly-varying capacitance easily derived from the data-sheet of the selected MOSFET. You can reuse the values I have for the passive elements and bring them back into your own simulation template. After a few seconds, you have the operating point with all the necessary waveforms:

[image]

Finally, if you want the control-to-output transfer function for stabilizing your loop, then you can add a voltage-controlled oscillator (VCO) and enjoy the ability of SIMPLIS to extract the ac response from a switching circuit what LTspice cannot *easily* do. With the below example, the simulation is done in 5 s:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the models. I believe that I understand what's going on in it for the most part, I only have a few questions:

1: is C1 meant to be the capacitor in the resonant tank?

2: From what I understand, models of actual converters model in the parallel inductance of the last inductor into the windings of the primary of the transformer. Is having it separate in your model just a simulation thing, or am I missing something?

3: How exactly is the transformer being defined? I don't exactly understand the syntax.

Comment: The transformer is modeled as a simple turns ratio 1:N to which you add an external magnetizing inductance and an external inductance. This latter is added whether you have it as part of the leakage inductance or as an externally-added element. The model remains the same either way. \$C_r\$ is the resonating capacitor, yes. Then the deadtime of the half-bridge is adjusted so that the magnetizing current discharges the MOSFET's capacitors and ensures ZVS.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems with your design:

- g1 gate drive signal is ground-referenced. You can't drive the MOSFET M1 because it's a high-side switch. So g1's reference should be connected to **p1** so that you can apply this drive signal across M1's gate-source.
- You don't have any dead time between the gate pulses. You should always leave some dead time because you'll be shorting the supply otherwise. It doesn't mean that the simulation won't work but shorting the supply momentarily will lead to unexpected results. Depending on the switching frequency, a few tens to a few hundred nanoseconds should be okay.
- I can't see the coupling between L3 and L2. This means that L3 and L2 will be taken as "individual inductors" by the simulator. You must add a simulation directive so that the simulator understands that L2 and L3 form a transformer. Something like `K L2 L3 1` should work. For further info visit [here](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-basic-steps-for-simulating-transformers.html).
- It appears that you tried to go for the split cap approach for the resonant cap (C4 and C2). But you also have C1 connected in series which will interact with the other two. This is meaningless and unnecessary. Get rid of either C1 (i.e. replace with short and change the values of C4 and C2) or the C4-C2 pair (i.e. connect p11 to GND).

I'm assuming that you are trying to run an open-loop simulation which doesn't require the frequency to be auto-adjusted for output regulation (You normally need a VCO for that purpose). It's the way I follow. It allows me to fine-adjust the output voltage by changing the frequency. And also it makes it easier to find the pole frequency which is the boundary of the capacitive region that we don't want the tank to operate in.

You need to make the resonant cap modification I mentioned above, and review your tank design i.e. re-calculate the component values. Looking at your tank, I can say that if you get rid of the C4-C2 pair and leave C1 (1u) only then the resonance frequency will be around 112 kHz (even with the C4-C2 pair this frequency will be slightly higher), and the pole frequency will be around 42 kHz. If you run the tank with ~49 kHz the operation point will be quite close to the capacitive region and the output will be way higher than expected.

Final note: Using net names instead of drawing connections makes your schematic difficult to read (I don't want to say "unreadable").

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to build a circuit with a regulated voltage, you will need feedback. In the document it shows the feedback loop:

[image]
Source [PDF for infineon app note AN 2012-09](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Application_Note_Resonant+LLC+Converter+Operation+and+Design_Infineon.pdf?fileId=db3a30433a047ba0013a4a60e3be64a1)

This section of the circuit is needed to give feedback to the switching circuit to regulate the voltage.